# Android Bottom Menu view click Menu

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-menu, android-bottomnav

Hello How can I do as it appears on the screen. Please.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tj46d.jpg)

Comment: use multiple `BottomNavigationView`'s

Comment: 1.Click BottomNavigationView okey 
2. click ?  
3.click ?